# prestodb| worker not found & v1/collector/general is not returning any values

Tags: presto

Hi I have configured `prestodb` with one `coordinator` and one `worker`.

when I run the `worker` I do get the message like

> - Discovery server connect succeeded for refresh (presto/general)
> - Discovery server connect succeeded for refresh (collector/general)
> - io.airlift.discovery.client.Announcer   Discovery server connect succeeded for announce

however when I run a query it says `worker not available`.

also when I try to see if the below urls works 
 `http://<master>/v1/service/presto/general` - works ( i can see both nodes)

However when i use 
`http://<master>//v1/service/collector/general` - doesn't work below is the result 
`{"environment":"dev","services":[]}`

---

## Server config.properties

```
coordinator=true
node-scheduler.include-coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8000
query.max-memory=50GB
query.max-memory-per-node=3GB
discovery-server.enabled=true
discovery.uri=http://gdcrtdev01.[domain]:8000
```

## Worker config.properties

```
coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=8000
query.max-memory=50GB
query.max-memory-per-node=1GB
discovery.uri=http://gdcrtdev01.[domain]:8000
```

Comment: Can you please post your config.properties for coordinator and worker?

Comment: added the configs to my original post

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same binary packages for worker and coordinator? Do you see the version of Presto of each of the node?

Comment: yes i already saw that, the matching versions, as a thing to look out for. its all the same version.